# Difference of Activation Functions in Neural Networks in general

Tags: neural-network, activation-function

I have studied the activation function types for neural networks. The functions themselves are quite straightforward, but the application difference is not entirely clear.

It's reasonable that one differentiates between logical and linear type functions, depending on the desired binary/continuous output but what is the advantage of sigmoid function over the simple linear one?

ReLU is especially difficult to understand for me, for instance: what is the point to use a function that behaves like linear in case of positive inputs but is "flat" in case of negatives? What is the intuition behind this? Or is it just a simple trial-error thing, nothing more?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A similar question was asked on CV: [Comprehensive list of activation functions in neural networks with pros/cons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/115258/12359).

I copy below one of the answers:

> One such a list, though not much exhaustive:
>   http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/
>
> #### Commonly used activation functions
>
> Every activation function (or *non-linearity*) takes a single number
>   and performs a certain fixed mathematical operation on it. There are
>   several activation functions you may encounter in practice:

[image][image]

> **Left:** Sigmoid non-linearity
>   squashes real numbers to range between [0,1] **Right:** The tanh
>   non-linearity squashes real numbers to range between [-1,1].
>
> **Sigmoid.** The sigmoid non-linearity has the mathematical form $\sigma(x) = 1 / (1 + e^{-x})$ and is shown in the image above on
>   the left. As alluded to in the previous section, it takes a
>   real-valued number and "squashes" it into range between 0 and 1. In
>   particular, large negative numbers become 0 and large positive numbers
>   become 1. The sigmoid function has seen frequent use historically
>   since it has a nice interpretation as the firing rate of a neuron:
>   from not firing at all (0) to fully-saturated firing at an assumed
>   maximum frequency (1). In practice, the sigmoid non-linearity has
>   recently fallen out of favor and it is rarely ever used. It has two
>   major drawbacks:
>
> - *Sigmoids saturate and kill gradients*. A very undesirable property of the sigmoid neuron is that when the neuron's activation
>     saturates at either tail of 0 or 1, the gradient at these regions is
>     almost zero. Recall that during backpropagation, this (local) gradient
>     will be multiplied to the gradient of this gate's output for the whole
>     objective. Therefore, if the local gradient is very small, it will
>     effectively "kill" the gradient and almost no signal will flow through
>     the neuron to its weights and recursively to its data. Additionally,
>     one must pay extra caution when initializing the weights of sigmoid
>     neurons to prevent saturation. For example, if the initial weights are
>     too large then most neurons would become saturated and the network
>     will barely learn.
> - *Sigmoid outputs are not zero-centered*. This is undesirable since neurons in later layers of processing in a Neural Network (more on
>     this soon) would be receiving data that is not zero-centered. This has
>     implications on the dynamics during gradient descent, because if the
>     data coming into a neuron is always positive (e.g. $x > 0$
>     elementwise in $f = w^Tx + b$)), then the gradient on the weights
>     $w$ will during backpropagation become either all be positive, or
>     all negative (depending on the gradient of the whole expression
>     $f$). This could introduce undesirable zig-zagging dynamics in the
>     gradient updates for the weights. However, notice that once these
>     gradients are added up across a batch of data the final update for the
>     weights can have variable signs, somewhat mitigating this issue.
>     Therefore, this is an inconvenience but it has less severe
>     consequences compared to the saturated activation problem above.
>
> **Tanh.** The tanh non-linearity is shown on the image above on the right. It squashes a real-valued number to the range [-1, 1]. Like the
>   sigmoid neuron, its activations saturate, but unlike the sigmoid
>   neuron its output is zero-centered. Therefore, in practice the *tanh
>   non-linearity is always preferred to the sigmoid nonlinearity.* Also
>   note that the tanh neuron is simply a scaled sigmoid neuron, in
>   particular the following holds: $ \tanh(x) = 2 \sigma(2x) -1  $.
>
> [image][image]
>
> **Left:** Rectified Linear
>   Unit (ReLU) activation function, which is zero when x < 0 and then
>   linear with slope 1 when x > 0. **Right:** A plot from Krizhevsky
>   et al. (pdf) paper indicating the 6x improvement in convergence
>   with the ReLU unit compared to the tanh unit.
>
> **ReLU.** The Rectified Linear Unit has become very popular in the last few years. It computes the function $f(x) = \max(0, x)$. In
>   other words, the activation is simply thresholded at zero (see image
>   above on the left). There are several pros and cons to using the
>   ReLUs:
>
> - (+) It was found to greatly accelerate (e.g. a factor of 6 in [Krizhevsky et
>     al.](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/imagenet.pdf)) the
>     convergence of stochastic gradient descent compared to the
>     sigmoid/tanh functions. It is argued that this is due to its linear,
>     non-saturating form.
> - (+) Compared to tanh/sigmoid neurons that involve expensive operations (exponentials, etc.), the ReLU can be implemented by simply
>     thresholding a matrix of activations at zero.
> - (-) Unfortunately, ReLU units can be fragile during training and can "die". For example, a large gradient flowing through a ReLU neuron
>     could cause the weights to update in such a way that the neuron will
>     never activate on any datapoint again. If this happens, then the
>     gradient flowing through the unit will forever be zero from that point
>     on. That is, the ReLU units can irreversibly die during training since
>     they can get knocked off the data manifold. For example, you may find
>     that as much as 40% of your network can be "dead" (i.e. neurons that
>     never activate across the entire training dataset) if the learning
>     rate is set too high. With a proper setting of the learning rate this
>     is less frequently an issue.
>
> **Leaky ReLU.** Leaky ReLUs are one attempt to fix the "dying ReLU" problem. Instead of the function being zero when x < 0, a leaky ReLU will instead have a small negative slope (of 0.01, or so). That is, the function computes $f(x) = \mathbb{1}(x < 0) (\alpha x) + \mathbb{1}(x>=0) (x) $ where $\alpha$ is a small constant. Some people report success with this form of activation function, but the results are not always consistent. The slope in the negative region can also be made into a parameter of each neuron, as seen in PReLU neurons, introduced in [Delving Deep into Rectifiers](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852), by Kaiming He et al., 2015. However, the consistency of the benefit across tasks is presently unclear.

[image]

> **Maxout**. Other types of units have been proposed that do not have the functional form $f(w^Tx + b)$ where a non-linearity is applied
>   on the dot product between the weights and the data. One relatively
>   popular choice is the Maxout neuron (introduced recently by
>   [Goodfellow et
>   al.](http://www-etud.iro.umontreal.ca/~goodfeli/maxout.html)) that
>   generalizes the ReLU and its leaky version. The Maxout neuron computes
>   the function $\max(w_1^Tx+b_1, w_2^Tx + b_2)$. Notice that both
>   ReLU and Leaky ReLU are a special case of this form (for example, for
>   ReLU we have $w_1, b_1 = 0$). The Maxout neuron therefore enjoys
>   all the benefits of a ReLU unit (linear regime of operation, no
>   saturation) and does not have its drawbacks (dying ReLU). However,
>   unlike the ReLU neurons it doubles the number of parameters for every
>   single neuron, leading to a high total number of parameters.
>
> This concludes our discussion of the most common types of neurons and
>   their activation functions. As a last comment, it is very rare to mix
>   and match different types of neurons in the same network, even though
>   there is no fundamental problem with doing so.
>
> **TLDR**: "*What neuron type should I use?*" Use the ReLU non-linearity, be careful with your learning rates and possibly
>   monitor the fraction of "dead" units in a network. If this concerns
>   you, give Leaky ReLU or Maxout a try. Never use sigmoid. Try tanh, but
>   expect it to work worse than ReLU/Maxout.

---

> License:
>   The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) 2015 Andrej Karpathy
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.*

Comment: Thanks, this summary gives some insight, but, frankly, I still cannot fathom some details intuitively (e. g. why ReLU "greatly accelerates convergence of SGD"), and most of all: which one to select? Based on the conclusion, Maxout is the best and that's the end of it. But apart from the fact that Maxout is not implemented in the most popular packages (in Keras, for instance), it seems me reasonable that at least in the last layer other types should be placed (sigmoid for biclassification for instance).